How to set focus on a ShadCN Command component when rendered in Lexical Editor's TypeaheadMenuPlugin?
I’m working with a Command component from ShadCN within a LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin, and I want to set focus programmatically on the Command component as soon as it renders.
I’m using useRef and useEffect to focus the component, but it’s not working as expected.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin } from "@lexical/react/LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin";
import { Command, CommandGroup, CommandItem, CommandList } from "@/components/ui/command"; // ShadCN Command component

const ComponentPickerMenuPlugin: React.FC = () => {
  const commandRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (commandRef.current) {
      commandRef.current.focus(); // Trying to set focus on Command component
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <LexicalTypeaheadMenuPlugin
        menuRenderFn={(anchorElementRef) =>
          anchorElementRef.current
            ? ReactDOM.createPortal(
                <Command ref={commandRef} tabIndex={0} className="rounded-lg">
                  <CommandList>
                    <CommandGroup heading="Suggestions">
                      <CommandItem>Option 1</CommandItem>
                      <CommandItem>Option 2</CommandItem>
                    </CommandGroup>
                  </CommandList>
                </Command>,
                anchorElementRef.current
              )
            : null
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default ComponentPickerMenuPlugin;


I'm using the ShadCN Command component inside Lexical's TypeaheadMenuPlugin.
I’ve added tabIndex={0} to make the component focusable.
The useEffect runs after the component renders, but the focus doesn’t seem to be applied.

How can I successfully programmatically set focus on the ShadCN Command component when it renders within Lexical's TypeaheadMenuPlugin?

when it comes to focusing components between open/active states you need to wrap the focus setter around a setTimeout with a very small delay, so your code should look something like this:
useEffect(() => {
  if (commandRef.current) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      commandRef.current.focus();
    }, 50)
  }
}, []);

if you're trying to highlight a CommandItem component, you'll want to set the data-selected attribute alongside the focus, which looks something like this:
useEffect(() => {
  if (commandItemRef.current) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      commandItemRef.current.setAttribute("data-selected", "true")
      commandRef.current.focus();
    }, 50)
  }
}, []);

